# Element in the VisualElementRenderer is not my generic type

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, wkwebview

I followed the example - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview/ to create a hybrid web view. It works fine in Andriod project but I have issues with the iOS project. In the OnElementChanged override, the Element property is always Xamarin.Forms.Element type which is the base type and not my generic view type (TElement). I have rechecked my code multiple times but cannot find any fixes. If I download the original code and run it, it works fine. The issue is only in my project.

Can anybody give me pointers as to why I might not be getting the generic TElement type. In the original project , the TElement type is HybridWebView. In mine I have a different name but with almost all the same properties and methods.

Below are some of my code. It is really easy to replicate the issue. Just create a new Xamarin.Forms solution and add my code. You will see the issue on this lie - var ele = Element; //ELEMENT HERE IS NOt SBMHybridWebView

The custom control in PCL

```
    public class SBMHybridWebView : Xamarin.Forms.View
{
}
```

The iOS Renderer (off-course I have added the ExportRenderer)

```
    public class SBMHybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<SBMHybridWebView, WKWebView>, IWKScriptMessageHandler
{
    const string JavaScriptFunction = "function invokeCSharpAction(data){window.webkit.messageHandlers.invokeAction.postMessage(data);}";
    WKUserContentController userController;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SBMHybridWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            userController = new WKUserContentController();
            var script = new WKUserScript(new NSString(JavaScriptFunction), WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, false);
            userController.AddUserScript(script);
            userController.AddScriptMessageHandler(this, "invokeAction");

            var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration { UserContentController = userController };
            var webView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
            SetNativeControl(webView);
        }
        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            //Clean up code
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var ele = Element; //ELEMENT HERE IS NOt SBMHybridWebView
        }
    }

    public void DidReceiveScriptMessage(WKUserContentController userContentController, WKScriptMessage message)
    {
        //Element.InvokeAction(message.Body.ToString());
    }
}
```

The XAML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:localcontrol="clr-namespace:App2.Control;assembly=App2"
             x:Class="App2.View.Page1">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="60" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <localcontrol:SBMHybridWebView Grid.Row="0" />
  </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Add the relevant parts of your code to the question. It's very hard to help without more information.

Comment: I have edited the post

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause which I cannot explain. In my iOS project, I had my SBMHybridWebViewRenderer in Renderer folder. Somehowm iOS does not like the renderer to be in a folder. Moving it to the root of the project (but keeping the same namespace) solved the issue. WHY? I dont know. I would have expected it to work regardless of where I place the file.

I thought I will post this just incase someone else has the same issue.

Comment: You should be able to put renderers anywhere you want in an iOS project, folders don't matter. Maybe it was namespace-related?

Comment: It was not namespace related. I did test that. It needs the render to be in the root folder. I could still keep my original namespace. You are welcome to test this. Only takes 5 mins to create a sample project and copy the code from -https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview/ .Note that this is the one that inherits from the ViewRenderer and not the ones that inherit from the normal renderers such as ButtonRenderer or LabelRenderer. The normal ones work fine.

Comment: I tried every possible variation with the code from the question in a clean project. `Element` is always of the correct type (`SBMHybridWebView`). Maybe it would be helpful to let us know what type you got there. Or try to share your sample project (through Github for example).